# Strange characters from output in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

Over the past few years there have been some Linux systems that will output strange characters when running various commands. Here's an example of my output from the `sensors` command on one of those machines:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +45.5Â°C  (crit = +126.0Â°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +44.0Â°C  (high = +100.0Â°C, crit = +100.0Â°C)
Core 1:       +45.0Â°C  (high = +100.0Â°C, crit = +100.0Â°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        -62.0Â°C  (high = +95.0Â°C, crit = +99.0Â°C)
```

Notice the `Â` character all over the place. Why does this happen in some environments and not others? What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either use a terminal program that understands UTF-8, or tell your shell to not use UTF-8 via `$LANG`.

```
>>> print u'°'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
Â°
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized I hadn't set this up in Putty on Windows. That is where the problem was happening, not when using the terminal in various Linux distros. My mistake!

Comment: In this case PuTTY would be your terminal program.

Comment: This worked for me. Single quotes had turned into `â` on PuTTY, but it was fixed after I changed the Window > Translation > Remote character set to UTF8

Comment: In my case I was seeing strange characters when logging in from Solaris 10 to Linux.  I did `export LC_ALL=en_IE.UTF-8` on the Linux host and set the Solaris terminal character encoding to UTF-8.  It was fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

You should set your locale to C:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```